# FOR XML AUTO and column name with space issue in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Here is my SQL

```
select 
   ID as [Emp ID],
   Name as [Employee name],
   Sal as [Salary] 
from Emp 
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('customers')
```

When I issue this SQL then unknown data is added in xml with my field name.

I got the xml like

```
<customers>
   <Emp>
     <Emp_x0020_ID>1</Emp_x0020_ID>
     <Employee_x0020_name>bob</Employee_x0020_name>
     <Salary>2020</Salary>
   </Emp>
   <Emp>
     <Emp_x0020_ID>2</Emp_x0020_ID>
     <Employee_x0020_name>keith</Employee_x0020_name>
     <Salary>6500</Salary>
   </Emp>
   <Emp>
     <Emp_x0020_ID>3</Emp_x0020_ID>
     <Employee_x0020_name>markc</Employee_x0020_name>
     <Salary>5400</Salary>
   </Emp>
 </customers>
```

It shows `<Emp_x0020_ID>` instead of this `<Emp ID>` because I mention column alias with space like "Emp ID". how could modify my SQL as a result space will not be ignore I mean my xml would look like

```
<customers>
  <Emp>
    <Emp ID>1</Emp ID>
    <Employee name>bob</Employee name>
    <Salary>2020</Salary>
   </Emp>
</customers>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid XML, so don't even think about it.

This is OK

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<a><bc>1</bc></a>'
```

This fails

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<a><b c>1</b c></a>'
```

Multi-word element names are invalid

Comment: +1 exactly - just don't use spaces in XML tags - then this problem never occurs :-)