# Field name with space problem in case of for xml auto output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, for-xml

my sql is very simple

select ID as [Employee ID], EmpName as [Employee Name], Sal as [Salary] from Emp FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('customers')

when i execute this sql then i am getting output in xml format. the xml output is

```
<customers>
<Emp>
  <Employee_x0020_ID>1</Employee_x0020_ID>
  <Employee_x0020_Name>Tridip</Employee_x0020_Name>
  <Salary>2500</Salary>
</Emp>
<Emp>
  <Employee_x0020_ID>2</Employee_x0020_ID>
  <Employee_x0020_Name>Ari</Employee_x0020_Name>
  <Salary>4000</Salary>
</Emp>
<Emp>
  <Employee_x0020_ID>3</Employee_x0020_ID>
  <Employee_x0020_Name>Dibyendu</Employee_x0020_Name>
  <Salary>3500</Salary>
</Emp>
</customers>
```

if u see the xml filed name then u can understand that field name is generated dynamically
due to space. <Employee_x0020_ID>1</Employee_x0020_ID> this is dynamically generated but i want it should be generated like <Employee ID>1</Employee ID>. i want space should be maintain in the xml filed name. so please tell me what to do........thanks

Comment: Asking the same question twice and expecting different answers is... odd. What you're asking for isn't XML, so don't expect something that produces XML to produce it.

Comment: You may ask again, just don't do it on the same month, week let alone month. Maybe next year they will relax the XML specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the output you are looking for that pretends to be XML.
You won't even be able to cast it to XML in any parser (at least it shouldn't - it won't in SQL Server).

```
;with emp(ID, EmpName, Sal) as (select
    1, 'tridip', 2500 union all select
    2, 'ari', 4000)

select replace(convert(varchar(max),(
    select ID as [Employee ID], EmpName as [Employee Name], Sal as [Salary] 
    from Emp 
    FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('customers'))),
    '_x0020_', ' ')
```

Output (reformatted for clarity - SQL Server returns it all on one line)

```
<customers><Emp><Employee ID>1</Employee ID><Employee Name>tridip
</Employee Name><Salary>2500</Salary></Emp><Emp>
<Employee ID>2</Employee ID><Employee Name>ari</Employee Name>
<Salary>4000</Salary></Emp></customers>
```

Answer (score 6):

From [XML Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_elements.asp) at W3Schools:

> XML elements must follow these naming rules:

- Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
- Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
- Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- **Names cannot contain spaces**

> Any name can be used, no words are reserved.

(Emphasis added)

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is the same question?
[FOR XML AUTO and column name with space problem in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751297/for-xml-auto-and-column-name-with-space-problem-in-sql-server-2005)

The answer is the same. You can not have a space in a XML tag name.