# Issue with colunns in XML in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have sample data

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (users int, ts int, name varchar(10), [1] int);

INSERT INTO @Table1 (users, ts, name, [1])
VALUES (1, 1, 'Raj', 0),
       (1, 3, 'maj', 2534),
       (1, 10, 'yes', 1458);
```

If I'm trying to add

```
select
    'test' as 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode',
    users AS 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode',
    name as 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode',
    [1] AS 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode/1'   
from 
    @Table1
where 
    ts = 3
for xml path('xmlexecute'), elements;
```

I get an error:

> Msg 6850, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Column name 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode/1' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '1'(0x0031) is the first character at fault.

how can I get the result like this :

```
 <xmlexecute>
      <job>
        <branch>
          <FBEN>
            <opcode>1</opcode>
            <opcode>3</opcode>
            <opcode>maj</opcode>
             <1> 2534   </1>
          </FBEN>
        </branch>
      </job>
    </xmlexecute>
```

Comment: XML is fairly strict - you can't have an element name which starts with a number. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756402/field-name-with-space-problem-in-case-of-for-xml-auto-output for similar question.

Comment: then what I need to do over come this @JohnD

Comment: Dude...what else could be the answer? Use any other character that does not start with a numeric character. Not rocket science.

Comment: For example you could use `job/branch/FBEN/opcode/column1` instead of `job/branch/FBEN/opcode/1`.

Comment: ok then I will suggest the same to my Data Architect @JohnD

Answer (score 1):

This is the same answer as to your [other question - with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40996165/5089204):

It is **impossible to name an element `<1>`**! XML will not allow this! [Look at "XML naming rules"](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp).

Well, you could create a string, which **looks like XML**, but this is a string and not XML. In most cases the best choice was, to push this content into an attribute's value... This depends on your needs.

Btw: I would really re-think naming a column `[1]`. This will be - for sure! - a pain in neck in the future...

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (users int, ts int, name varchar(10), [1] int);

INSERT INTO @Table1 (users, ts, name, [1])
VALUES (1, 1, 'Raj', 0),
       (1, 3, 'maj', 2534),
       (1, 10, 'yes', 1458);
select
(
    select
        'test' as [opcode]
        ,''
        ,users AS [opcode]
        ,''
        ,name as [opcode] 
        ,''
        ,[1] AS [opcode] --or any other (valid) name, start with an "@" for an attribute
    from 
        @Table1
    where 
        ts = 1
    for xml path('FBEN'),ROOT('branch'),TYPE
) AS job
FOR XML PATH('xmlexecute')
;
```

The result

```
<xmlexecute>
  <job>
    <branch>
      <FBEN>
        <opcode>test</opcode>
        <opcode>1</opcode>
        <opcode>Raj</opcode>
        <opcode>0</opcode>
      </FBEN>
    </branch>
  </job>
</xmlexecute>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:(this gives exactly the result you want):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (users int, ts int, name varchar(10), [1] int);

INSERT INTO @Table1 (users, ts, name, [1])
VALUES 
(1, 1, 'Raj', 0),       (1, 3, 'maj', 2534),       (1, 10, 'yes', 1458);

select replace((replace((replace((
 select
    users AS 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode',
    ts as 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode1',
    name as 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode2',
    [1] AS 'job/branch/FBEN/zxdg1'   
from 
    @Table1
where 
    ts = 3
for xml path('xmlexecute'), elements),'opcode1','opcode')),'opcode2','opcode')),'zxdg1','1')
```

> Output:

```
<xmlexecute>
        <job>
           <branch>
              <FBEN>
               <opcode>1</opcode>
               <opcode>3</opcode>
               <opcode>maj</opcode>
               <1>2534</1>
            </FBEN>
           </branch>
         </job>
 </xmlexecute>
```

Comment: No! If ever possible one **should not treat XML on string level!** This has various side effects and might lead to absolutely unpredictable errors. Just imagine, the word "opcode1" is - why ever - contained somewhere else...

Comment: And btw: Your output is a string. It **looks like XML**, but it isn't. You would not be able to use XML-methods with this. Try `CAST(YourResult AS XML)`... You'll get the same error as the OP...